# flink job submit through sql-client.sh sometime without any checkpoint (what is the way to alter it) or how to recover in case of failure

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

for example sql-client.sh embedded
insert into wap_fileused_daily(orgId, pdate, platform, platform_count) select u.orgId, u.pdate, coalesce(p.platform,'other'), sum(u.isMessage) as platform_count from users as u left join ua_map_platform as p on u.uaType = p.uatype where u.isMessage = 1 group by u.orgId, u.pdate, p.platform

it will show up as:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okOgJ.png)

there will never be any checkpoint.
Question: 1) how to trigger checkpoint ( alert job)
2) how to recover in case of failure

Answer (score 0):

You can specify execution configuration parameters in the SQL Client YAML file. For example, the following should work:

```yaml
configuration:
  execution.checkpointing.interval: 42
```

Comment: Here is the my sql.yml

Comment: we sure have that configuration. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request on flink:https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-147%3A+Support+Checkpoints+After+Tasks+Finished